# Arrive "by" or "on" a specific train?

Tags: prepositions

I happened to read a "programme of visit" of a foreign delegation which stated that the delegation would arrive in [name of city] *by train H702*. Obviously, H702 is the designation of a specific train. As for me, I would probably say "on train H702" in such a case. Similarly, I would go somewhere **by** bus (just to indicate the means of transport), but **on** bus 111 (when I indicate a specific bus route). Am I wrong in my thinking?

Comment: I think most people would agree with you.

Comment: However, "train H702" can be a designation of multiple physical trains running at various times, so it could be as appropriate as "by train".

Comment: @Nemo   There is an entry in *English Grammar in Use* by Raymond Murphy: 
"You cannot use **by** if you say "**my** car / **the** train / **a** taxi". 
We use **by** + *noun* without "a/the/my". We say:
**by car** _but_ **in my car**
**by train** _but_ **on the train**
...
We use **on** for bicycles and public transport (buses, trains, etc): --> We travelled **on the 6.45 train** ."

Comment: Hence it should be either "the delegation will arrive **on** the H702 train" or "the delegation will arrive **on** (the) train H702". The preposition **by** is inappropriate here. Objections?